# Convergence of rasch "algorithm did not converge", "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred"

Tags: r, estimation, psych

I have a problem, I use the function "rasch" package "ltm" in R to get an estimate of the difficulties but when i use it for

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                       1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,
                       1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,
                       0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),ncol = 6, nrow = 16))

rasch(x)
```

I get many warning as

```
"glm.fit: algorithm did not converge"Warning message:
"glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred"Warning message:
"glm.fit: algorithm did not converge"Warning message:
"glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred"Warning message:
"glm.fit: algorithm did not converge"Warning message:
```

How can I fix the problem?

Please help!